# That and the demonstrative pronouns

Tags: pronoun, accusative, definite-article, nominative, demonstrative-pronoun

I'm missing something, perhaps is the understanding of demonstrative pronouns. In (from [youtube](https://youtu.be/2QPZu6YNr78?t=385)) `That is Peter.` or

```
Das ist Peter.
```

`Das` is being used as a demonstrative pronoun, right? But the case, is it neutral? Shouldn't it match with Peter? Then would be

```
Der ist Peter.
```

And (to confuse me a bit more) [GERMAN DEMONSTRATIVE PRONOUNS “JENER”](https://language-easy.org/german/grammar/pronouns/demonstrative/) seems to translate `that` also. Perhaps I should say

Jener ist Peter.

or not?

Comment: There it says `If the word "das" means "this", there are no different words for m/f/n`. Should I assume the same when "das" means "that"?

Comment: What about `these`/`those` can I just use `das` for them also?

Comment: @CarstenS: Please do not use the comment function to answer questions. Use the answer functions to post proper answers instead please. See also https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487